# PySpark Window "custom rank"

Tags: pyspark

I want to rank duplicates present in a table using PySpark. 2 rows are duplicates if they appear one after the other.

Assume with store only 2 events for each vehicle:

| id | vehicle | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 | 2023-04-10 08:19:29 | event_1 |
| 2 | v1 | 2023-04-10 08:41:01 | event_2 |
| 3 | v1 | 2023-04-10 09:41:01 | event_1 |
| 4 | v1 | 2023-04-10 10:41:01 | event_2 |
| 5 | v1 | 2023-04-10 11:41:01 | event_2 |
| 6 | v1 | 2023-04-10 12:41:01 | event_1 |
| 7 | v1 | 2023-04-10 13:41:01 | event_1 |
| 8 | v1 | 2023-04-10 14:41:01 | event_2 |

In this table, the duplicates are rows with id 5 and 7.
I would like to have the ranking in this way:

| id | vehicle | timestamp | event | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 | 2023-04-10 08:19:29 | event_1 | 1 |
| 2 | v1 | 2023-04-10 08:41:01 | event_2 | 1 |
| 3 | v1 | 2023-04-10 09:41:01 | event_1 | 1 |
| 4 | v1 | 2023-04-10 10:41:01 | event_2 | 1 |
| 5 | v1 | 2023-04-10 11:41:01 | event_2 | 2 |
| 6 | v1 | 2023-04-10 12:41:01 | event_1 | 1 |
| 7 | v1 | 2023-04-10 13:41:01 | event_1 | 2 |
| 8 | v1 | 2023-04-10 14:41:01 | event_2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

We can use `window` funcitons for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

from pyspark.sql.window import Window

windowSpec  = Window.orderBy("id")
window_grp = Window.partitionBy("sum_grp").orderBy("timestamp")

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','v1','2023-04-10 08:19:29','event_1'),
('2','v1','2023-04-10 08:41:01','event_2'),
('3','v1','2023-04-10 09:41:01','event_1'),
('4','v1','2023-04-10 10:41:01','event_2'),
('5','v1','2023-04-10 11:41:01','event_2'),
('6','v1','2023-04-10 12:41:01','event_1')],['id','vehicle','timestamp','event'])

grp_df = df.withColumn("lag", lag("event",1).over(windowSpec)).\
  withColumn("temp", when((col("event")==col("lag")),lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))).\
    withColumn("sum_grp", sum(col("temp")).over(windowSpec)).\
      withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window_grp)).\
        drop(*['lag','temp','sum_grp'])

grp_df.show(10,False)

#+---+-------+-------------------+-------+----+
#|id |vehicle|timestamp          |event  |rank|
#+---+-------+-------------------+-------+----+
#|1  |v1     |2023-04-10 08:19:29|event_1|1   |
#|2  |v1     |2023-04-10 08:41:01|event_2|1   |
#|3  |v1     |2023-04-10 09:41:01|event_1|1   |
#|4  |v1     |2023-04-10 10:41:01|event_2|1   |
#|5  |v1     |2023-04-10 11:41:01|event_2|2   |
#|6  |v1     |2023-04-10 12:41:01|event_1|1   |
```